# Fastest database engine for caching?

Tags: php, database, caching

I use MySQL for my primary database, where I keep the actual objects. When an object is rendered using a template, rendering takes a lot of time.

Because of that I've decided to cache the produced HTML. Right now I store the cache in files, named appropriate, and it does work significantly faster. I am however aware that it is not the best way to do so.

I need a (preferably key-value) database to store my cache in. I cannot use a caching proxy because I still need to process the cached HTML. Is there such a database with a PHP front end?

**Edit:** If I use memcached, and I cache about a million pages, won't I run out of RAM?

**Edit 2:** And again, I have **a lot** of HTML to cache (gigabytes of it).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> If I use memcached, and I cache about
>   a million pages, won't I run out of
>   RAM?

### Memcached

memcached is also a real solid product(like redis more) used at all big sites to keep them up and running. Almost al active tweets(which user fetch) are stored in memcached for insane performance.

If you want to be fast you should have your active dataset in memory. But yeah if the dataset is bigger then your available memory you should(should always store data in persistent datastore because memcached is volatile) store data in a persistent datastore like for example mysql. When it's not available in memory you will try and fetch it from datastore and cache it memcache for future reference(with expire header).

### Redis

I really like [redis](http://code.google.com/p/redis/) because it is an advanced key-value store with insane performance

> Redis is an advanced key-value store.
>   It is similar to memcached but the
>   dataset is not volatile, and values
>   can be strings, exactly like in
>   memcached, but also lists, sets, and
>   ordered sets. All this data types can
>   be manipulated with atomic operations
>   to push/pop elements, add/remove
>   elements, perform server side union,
>   intersection, difference between sets,
>   and so forth. Redis supports different
>   kind of sorting abilities.

Redis has a [VM](http://antirez.com/post/redis-virtual-memory-story.html) so you don't need a seperate persisent datastore. I really like redis because of all the available [commands](http://code.google.com/p/redis/wiki/CommandReference) (power :)?). This [tutorial](http://simonwillison.net/static/2010/redis-tutorial/) by simon willison displays(a lot of) the raw power which redis has.

### Speed

Redis is **pretty fast!**, 110000 SETs/second, 81000 GETs/second in an entry level Linux box. [Check the benchmarks](http://code.google.com/p/redis/wiki/Benchmarks).

### Commits

Redis is more actively developed. 8 hours ago antirez(redis) [commited](https://github.com/antirez/redis/commit/6a246b1e7e9df7d7c104545d6d99819c6842511a) something versus memcached 12 November latest [commit](https://github.com/memcached/memcached/commit/af48b1005639d3cb1dea4e08dd9d2e33a2289a95).

### Install Redis

Redis is insanely easy to install. It has no dependencies. You only have to perform:

```
make
./redis-server redis.conf #start redis
```

to compile redis(Awesome :)?).

### Install Memcached

Memcached has dependency(libevent) which makes it more difficult to [install](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewInstallFromSource).

```
wget http://memcached.org/latest
tar -zxvf memcached-1.x.x.tar.gz
cd memcached-1.x.x
./configure
make && make test
sudo make install
```

not totally true because memcached has libevent dependency and `./configure` will fail of `libevent` is missing. But then again they have [packages](http://code.google.com/p/memcached/wiki/NewInstallFromPackage) which are cool, but require `root` to install.

Comment: Sounds awesome. Is it better than storing the cache in the filesystem? Root is not a problem as I'm the server admin.

Comment: And would redis be better for storing serialized dictionaries? I use MySQL at the moment, but most of the user functionality is just pulling entries using a unique handle.

Comment: @Nick you probably don't have to do any(maybe little) serializing because redis has list/sets/sorted sets just to name a few. a dictionary can be put in a set, or just store a lot of keys to map all fields. Using mget is extremely fast. I would advice you to play with redis-cli to get a feeling of the power and how you could tackle a lot problems + tutorial from willison(good!)

Answer (score 4):

> Redis is pretty fast: 110,000
>   SETs/second

If speed is a concern, why use the network layer?

According to: http://tokutek.com/downloads/mysqluc-2010-fractal-trees.pdf

- InnoDB inserts ....................43,000 records per second AT ITS PEAK*;
- TokuDB inserts ....................34,000 records per second AT ITS PEAK*;
- G-WAN KV inserts ....100,000,000 records per second

(*) after a few thousands of inserts, performances degrade severely for InnoDB and TokuDB which end to write to disk when their cache and the system cache and the disk controller cache are full. See the PDF for an interesting discussion of the problems caused by the topology of the InnoDB database index (which severely breaks locality while the Fractals topology scales much better... but still not linearly).

Answer (score 2):

To clarify the answers into logical views:

- Flat Files are as fast the storage medium being used (DISK or RAM)
- An environment which caches in RAM the MRU (Most Recently Used) items
- Solution has a smart/fast hash index to all locations (what SQL systems rely on)

That combination will get you the best solution that you are looking for.

For argument sake, flat file or not - excluding a MEMORY ONLY solution - all engines use some form of flat file. The magic is knowing where your data is, and tuning reads to pull the data back most optimal. In the 80's at IBM we used a fixed record length flat file design - which wasn't optimized for disk space, it was optimized for I/O. Indexes then were based on Record Length * ROWID.

Now to your need, your ultimate performance for scale is to introduce a smart combination - we host over 1 million companies, with over 10 pages per company - 10 million files, plus js, css and images.

Theory 1) - You know your limitation is RAM - spool dynamic content to disk when feasible and drop such features as hit counters. Leverage NGINX or HIGHLY tune APACHE (or as we did, wrote our own web servers since 2001) - the whole concept is leverage RAM for the MOST USED, and have a very intelligent lookup for disk based content - normally the URI is fine.

Theory 2) - Trend Analysis and User Anticipation - I have spent years researching and developing systems that track trends. If I know a user will go path A, B, C, D - then when he hits B, I have already prefetched C and D. If I know a user will go A, B but may go E then D. You have the choice to pre-cache C and E, or for RAM sake prefetch D. and manually fetch C or E when the user picks that.

The Web Server we have developed along with some accounting systems I have developed over the years integrate Theory 2 to prefetch, with combinations of Smart Caching. We also store the content to disk in deflate - so the transport layer simply pumps the content onto the stack as 99% of the browsers support deflated streams. (It's faster to reflate before sending for that 1% than deflate 99% of the time)

Per the thought of MEMCACHED and SWAP - Disk speed is your enemy, however, tying up the kernel to manage that enemy is an epic fail! If you want to beat MEMCACHED performance, learn how to setup a RAM DISK and keep your deflated HOT requested items there!

** DISCLAIMER: This all assumes that you have enough bandwidth that your Infrastructure/Users bandwidth is not your bottleneck, but your servers are. @3FINC

Answer (score 1):

http://memcached.org/ + http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php

Answer (score 1):

Flat files are "technically" the fastest - but if you're looking for something with a PHP front end and just screams - take a look at postgres.

http://www.wikivs.com/wiki/MySQL_vs_PostgreSQL#Raw_Speed

For memory caching look at memcached

http://memcached.org/

*Edit: from your edit ... (redundant yes) ... if you cache that volume in memory you will have issues. Look into postgres columnar table queries or a quasi-custom flat file solution.

Comment: If flat files are the fastest, I'll stick with them.

Comment: There is no way flat files are the fastest, plus you have GC them yourself. Any memory caching will beat it.

Comment: Any and every database uses flat files for storing its data. Better to just use flat files directly instead of adding extra overhead for something as simple as caching. So yes, they are indeed the fastest.

Comment: Outside of memory caching, flat file databases are faster than any relational DB out there (even Oracle 11 has to make claims about catching up). There certainly are disadvantages regarding GC and the like, but remember even RD must map to physical location when running out of physical memory. (I suppose to avoid the downvote I should note that memory is of course faster than disk...but in large volumes you will *always* run out of memory)

Comment: The kernel should be able to deal with a memory hungry memcached quite well, shouldn't it? (memory swapping is pretty quick, or am I not getting the concept of it)

Comment: Honestly it depends on how you're maintaining reference to flat file locations. Mem swap is the same speed as disk access. It's all about time to find disk location. If you use memcached as the driver I think it'd probably be preferable to rolling your own in-memory referencing system.

Comment: @iivel Chances are the OP doesn't need more than a GB of memory cache, if he tunes his GC time correctly. Most of those caches are probably doing next door to nothing.

Comment: I need 6 GB at minimum. Our webserver has 16 GB of RAM but the demands grow, RAM is limited, but the disk space is not.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, using the file system is actually the fastest way to cache rendered templates without resorting to storing them in memory. Any database would simply add overhead and would make the whole thing slower by comparison.

Answer (score 0):

I would use [memcached](http://php.net/manual/en/book.memcache.php) or [APC](http://php.net/manual/en/book.apc.php). Depending if you need caching shared between servers. Memcached is a daemon you connect to, where APC is actually inside of PHP instance (a little faster). Both of them store the cache in memory so it's blazing fast.

Comment: If I have a lot of HTML to cache there might be an issue.

Comment: 5-6 GB (our web-server has 16 GB of RAM). There are two database servers with 2 GB each.

Comment: @Nick Are those all current? GC'ing (which is done for you in APC and memcached) can help "optimize" your cache for you, by only keeping the caches around that are the most helpful. Chances are if you had a memory cache on ~1GB of them I'd probably be as effective as ~5GB.

Answer (score 0):

In fact storing cache in files is really the fastest way to do this. But, if you're really interested in putting them into a database, you can check out [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/). MongoDB is a document-oriented database so there are no server-side joins, that's why it's faster than mysql (1. with php 2. there are a lot of benchmarks on the internet).